# how to refresh data in a fragment after changes by another activity

Tags: android

I am implementing a small app where I have a *list of items* **(1)**.
With a fab button I start another activity that is able to *add a new item* **(2)**.
In **(1)** I have a ViewModel loading data from a repository.
In **(2)** I store the new item on the repository.
When the user save the data in **(2)**, that activity is closed (calling `finish()`), but "of course" in **(1)** I don't see any change.

I read around that I should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on `ViewModel` used in **(1)**, but I do not understand where: in **(1)** in method `onResume()`? or in another place?

Can you help me? Maybe e simple tutorial explaining this specific aspect?

Comment: "I store the new item on the repository" - just have both viewmodels observing the same repository, which is your single source of truth? The view doesn't need to know when to refresh, it just knows what data to display - which is governed by the repository.  If your respository isn't setup to be reactive either using Observer pattern, or other libraries like LiveData, RxJava, Coroutines/Flow then I suggest you use one of these options. Maybe share your code.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, if I understand correctly the right way to organize the architecture so that this is not an issue is to create the `Repository` (one of the solutions) to return `LiveData` and having the 2 `ViewModels` depending on that `Repository`, right?

Comment: There are many options so I suggest just one way, not specifically the "right way".  However having a shared Repository instance that is observed by the View model means that view has to do nothing other than oberve that data.  You probably want something like `repeatOnLifeCycle` inside your fragment where you can perform the lookup for your data, or some reactive repository. https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/repeatonlifecycle-api-design-story-8670d1a7d333 - sharing your minimal code example might help expedite a solution suited to your current code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using just a repository without any modern storage like Room or Datastore and just save the data in memory(Repository) then you should make your repository Singleton and save items in LiveData OR Flows inside repository then observe it.